# Parsing JSON data with a local AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

I've got a php file on a webserver that executes queries to a MySQL database.

I'm testing a site on my pc (locally) that uses a js file with an AJAX request to get JSON data from that php file.

Is it possible to do it like this, or the js file must be put on the same domain server of the php file?

Because the `console.log` of the parsed data gives me this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I

This is the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    method:"POST", 
    crossDomain:true, 
    url:"url for the php file",
    data:{
        query: "SELECT * FROM course_categories;"
    },

    success: function(response){

        var course_categories=JSON.parse(response); 
        console.log(course_categories);
        var el="";
        console.log(course_categories.length);
        for(var i=0;i<(course_categories.length);i++)
        {

        }

    },

    error: function(request,error){
        console.log("ERROR: Request " + request + "\nSpecific Error: " + error);
    }
```

While this is the PHP call

```
<?php

//get all the courses from the database and reply using the JSON structure

//$mysqli=new msqli("localhost","username","password","dbname");

 $mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","hey","","db_name");


if(mysqli_connect_errno()) //returns a number of the error if there is any,              if not
{
echo json_encode("Error to connect to DBMS".mysqli_connect_error());

exit(); //closes the connection
}
else
{


$query=$_POST["query"];
    //$query="SELECT * FROM course_categories";
       $result=$mysqli->query($query); //do a query (->query) setted by $query, using the $mysqli variable, and store the data in $result 

if($result->num_rows >0) //if there is at least one row...
{
    $myArray= array(); //...create an array...
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
    { 
        //...and fetch it. Everytime this operation returns a row,
        $myArray[]=$row; //...and added to myArray ([] means autoincrement).
    }

}

echo json_encode(utf8ize($myArray));

 //free result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close(); 

}
```

Comment: could you please provide your code?

Comment: Could you please share some code

Comment: @Riccardo Lomazzi - That's because you have some error in your PHP code and javascript can't read or parse that as JSON. Check your php code and you'll fix that problem :)

Comment: I've added some code

Comment: What is the exact response in the console? And what does the function `utf8ize` do?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I`at line 1 of html file, where actually there's only a `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: That looks like a javascript error, what is the exact response from the php script? Not the error you get when you try to parse it.

Comment: Well the php script obviously responds `null`because it can't get the POST data. So when I substitute the query directly in the php file, it gives me the correct data from the db in JSON format.

Comment: and the utf8ize is a function that converts data in utf8, it's already tested and working. I think the problem is that the php is on another domain than the js file calling it.

Comment: @RiccardoLomazzi Perhaps adding `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` to the PHP file would resolve CORS issues? I don't think CORS is the issue though but it never hurts to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. All I had to do, was to remove the `crossDomain:true` line so that the JSON could actually parse the data.